# Making node specifications global instead of repeating them for each tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code to draw several tikzpictures, sharing the same node definition specifications.

How can I make these node definition specifications global instead of repeating them for each tikzpicture (with possible changing the position of begin point at (.1,.2))

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,3.);
\node [red] at (.1,.2) (begin){}
([shift={(-90.:1cm)}]begin.center) node (beginclip){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]begin.center) node (beginr){}
([shift={(30:4.cm)}]beginr.center) node (midtop){}
([shift={(-30:4.cm)}]midtop.center) node (end){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]end.center) node (endr){}
([shift={(-90.:1cm)}]endr.center) node (endrclip){}
([shift={(0:.5cm)}]beginr.center) node (arrowl){}
([shift={(180:.5cm)}]end.center) node (arrowr){}
;
\draw[blue, very thick] (begin.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] (beginr.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] (midtop.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] (end.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] (endr.center);
\path[clip] (beginclip.center) -- (begin.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] (beginr.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] (midtop.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] (end.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] (endr.center) -- (endrclip.center) -- cycle;
\pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{1.6}
\draw[blue, very thick] (3.76-\DeltaX,1.8) -- (3.76-\DeltaX,0) (3.76+\DeltaX,1.8) -- (3.76+\DeltaX,0);
\draw [blue, very thick] (3.76-\DeltaX,0.1) -- (3.76-\DeltaX,-0.1) node [blue, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.24cm] {-3.182}
 (3.76+\DeltaX,0.1) -- (3.76+\DeltaX,-0.1) node [blue, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.24cm] {3.182};
\draw [ultra thick, blue] (midtop.center) node [blue, fill=blue!8, xshift=0cm, yshift=-1.2cm] {accept Ho} (midtop.center|-0,0) node [blue, xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save these things in a `pic`, which also accepts parameters. Of course, you may choose more, less and/or different parameters.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
Hany/.style n args={3}{code={\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,3.);
\node [red] at (.1,.2) (begin){}
([shift={(-90.:1cm)}]begin.center) node (beginclip){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]begin.center) node (beginr){}
([shift={(30:4.cm)}]beginr.center) node (midtop){}
([shift={(-30:4.cm)}]midtop.center) node (end){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]end.center) node (endr){}
([shift={(-90.:1cm)}]endr.center) node (endrclip){}
([shift={(0:.5cm)}]beginr.center) node (arrowl){}
([shift={(180:.5cm)}]end.center) node (arrowr){}
;
\draw[blue, very thick] (begin.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] (beginr.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] (midtop.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] (end.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] (endr.center);
\path[clip] (beginclip.center) -- (begin.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] (beginr.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] (midtop.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] (end.center) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] (endr.center) -- (endrclip.center) -- cycle;
\draw[blue, very thick] (3.76-#1,1.8) -- (3.76-#1,0) (3.76+#1,1.8) -- (3.76+#1,0);
\draw [blue, very thick] (3.76-#1,0.1) -- (3.76-#1,-0.1) node [blue, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.24cm] {-3.182}
 (3.76+#1,0.1) -- (3.76+#1,-0.1) node [blue, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.24cm] {3.182};
\draw [ultra thick, blue] (midtop.center) node [blue, fill=blue!8, xshift=0cm,
yshift=-1.2cm] {#2} (midtop.center|-0,0) node [blue, xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {#3};
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Parameters \texttt{{1.6},{accept Ho},{X}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\pic at (-3,0) {Hany={1.6}{accept Ho}{X}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Parameters \texttt{{1.4},{accept He},{Y}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\pic at (-3,0) {Hany={1.4}{accept He}{Y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can the pic definition include only the node specifications without including the curves; because there are many variable curves drawn with many other lines and text.

Comment: @Hany Of course you can make virtually anything a pic (as long as it is compilable). Just add or remove whatever you find appropriate.

Comment: @ marmot Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @ marmot Thank you for your comment, I figured out how to do that.